# Pop up doesn't close even after clicking save button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an issue with my code:

If i do not select any value in my drop down button, it will show a pop up with the message *"please select value"*. After selecting a value, the pop up will not close and even after saving the data it is still showing.

Give me some suggestions to close the pop up while selecting the right value in my drop down.

Here my code

```
 error_notify('Please Select City', 'error');
 $('#orgCity').addClass('errorcolor');
```

Comment: Where is your code you use to open and close the popup?!

Comment: where `error_notify` come from?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a close pop up function in which you can hide pop up by their id or class name and trigger them with your selection from drop down.